# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: java, sql-server

i want to insert the record in sql server . Table name and columns are specified in this code,

```
      String str_date=date;

      DateFormat formatter ; 

      formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

      date1 = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);  

      System.out.println("Today is " +date1 );
```

---

```
     try{

      String query="INSERT INTO BULT_DATA " +
                "(ULDT_ID" +
                ",ULDT_DESC" +
                ",ULDT_DT" +
                ",ULDT_ULTH_ID" +
                ",ULDT_DATA_FILE" +
                ",ULDT_MAX_ROW_NO" +
                ",ULDT_REC_STS" +
                ",ULDT_CRE_USER_ID" +
                ",ULDT_CRE_DT" +
                ",ULDT_UPD_USER_ID" +
                ",ULDT_UPD_DT" +
                ",ULDT_APRV_USER_ID" +
                ",ULDT_APRV_DT)" +
                "VALUES ('"+
                uploadID+"','"+
                uploadDes+"','"+
                date1+"','" +
                templateID+"','"+
                dataFile+"','"+
                noRows+"','" +
                        "N','" +
                        "admin','" +
                        "2011-12-05 18:41:50.000','" +
                        "admin','" +
                        "2011-12-05 18:41:50.000','" +
                        "NULL','" +
                        "NULL')";


            System.out.println("query :: "+query);

        int stmnt= stmt.executeUpdate(query);

                 }catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

but i got this exception

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 5):

First, only American humans use `MM-DD-YYYY` format for dates - everyone/everything else, especially databases, uses the ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

JDBC when used correctly will handle formatting your object into your SQL for you.

Thirdly (and this is minor), prefer `stmt.execute()` over `stmt.executeUpdate()` for inserts - an insert is not an update, it's an insert. Although, it *will* work using either.

Putting it all together, you get something like this (for example):

```
String sql = "insert into table (int_col, date_col, boolean_col, text_col)" +
   " values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setObject(1, 7);
statement.setObject(2, new Date());
statement.setObject(3, true);
statement.setObject(4, "hello");
statement.execute();
```

Note:

- the use of placeholders `?` in the sql
- the use of `statement.setObject(n, object)`
- the absence of quotes around date and text placeholders

The JDBC driver will do all the necessary conversions and formatting for you for all "usual" java objects, especially enclosing values in quotes for you if quotes are required for that column/data type.

You can change your code around yourself to work in the way I've demonstrated here.

Comment: +1 Why do Americans think `MM-DD-YYYY` makes any sense? We write numbers from biggest to smallest: 927 is 9x100 2x10 7x1... 100's 10's 1's -w e don't write it 297! And what with feet and inches??? Let it go USA! Give it up! Join the rest of the world!

Answer (score 2):

[Use an ISO or ODBC date format](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp#DtFormatsInput) for all values. 
Or the legacy SQL Server `yyymmdd hh:nn:ss`

`MM/dd/yyyy` is not safe, neither are the the constants you gave for UPD_DT and ULDT_CRE_DT

```
'19980223 14:23:05'
{ts '1998-02-23 14:23:05'}
{d '1998-02-23'}
'1998-02-23T14:23:05'
```

And have you heard of SQL Injection, often caused by building SQL commands with string concatenation

Comment: Just to exemplify the following will work `insert into YourTable (dateColumn) values ('20121121 16:00:00')`

Comment: @Oybek: That is non-ISO and legacy SQL Server standard. See the link,

Answer (score 0):

your date1 object will be formatted using the standard `toString()` representation of `java.lang.Date`, which is unlikely to be compatible with the various date formats supported by your JDBC drivers.

Rather use another SimpleDateFormat object to format `date1` into your SQL Server default date format before appending it to your query.

Also, do yourself a favour and read up on PreparedStatements and paramaterised queries; they really make this sort of stuff easier.

Answer (score 0):

The above error also occur when setting upper and lower bound in spark sql

> conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string. at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception

What I did was to convert the bound to date, e.g lower bound = '2023-03-18' and upper bound '2023-03-19'. Then the error disappear because it will generate the boundaries **"WHERE condition" with "yyyy-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"** without the millisecond because that is where the problem stems from.